# Why services like Facebook, Disqus, Google, Twitter tell us that

Tags: javascript, html, external

Why services like Facebook Like Button, Disqus comments.. tell  us to add this code to our document

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And not simply to add this code that is the same thing?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script id="facebook-jssdk"src="//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5"></script>
```

Comment: to load asynchronously, would be a large part of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the browser finds the `<script src="...">` tag, it blocks further rendering of the page until the javascript has loaded (or the loading fails). Obviously, it's not what you want for your website, to be stuck due to external javascripts.

Facebook gives you a code that will load the javascript asynchronously, without interfering with your page loading.
Starting from HTML5, you also have the "async" attribute for the script tag that gives you a similar behaviour. `<script src="..." async></script>`

You can find more informations about javascript loading, in this article: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]; //line 1
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;//line 2
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;//line 3
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5"; //line 4
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);//line 5
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

just observe at line 1 and line 5 - it is just trying to ensure that

1) facebook's script should be the first script in the page.

2) facebook's script is loaded lazyly. That is, `document.ready()` event will not wait for this script to be loaded.